# Start a script with a barcode - Autohotkey

Tags: barcode, autohotkey

I have a script written that starts when the someone inputs "START SCRIPT" on the keyboard. I have a barcode that has this text in it, so when it's scanned it starts the script. The script launches a notepad file and deletes everything in the file. I then need to scan a barcode that enters a line of data into Notepad. After that I need to run a second script that saves the Notepad file and does a few other steps. I currently have the second script starting when "Ctrl+t" is pressed, but I'd like to automate this by having another barcode scanned. 
Does anyone have a good solution for this? I can't make it start with a line of text because that text gets entered into Notepad before it's saved and closed.

Comment: It would help us to follow what you're saying if you included the relevant bits of your code.

Comment: I'll paste the code below when I have a chance to retrieve the file.

Comment: I would skip notepad alltogether and directly write it to disk with filedelete, scan.txt (just to make sure the file is empty) then fileappend, scan.txt, scannedtext (which adds the scannedtext to the, just before non-existing, file)

Comment: I'm fairly new to the whole script writing thing (I know just enough to be dangerous), so I'm not following what you're saying...
Would it be possible for you to paste some code below for me to try out?